# Is "to be down to do something" grammatical and common usage?

Tags: grammar

So I have been hearing this construction quite a bit recently but couldnt find it in any of the dictionaries that I commonly use to look up things.
So I was wondering just how common it really is and if its only used in very colloquial speech or extends to other areas as well. Then I have also heard "to be down for" but Im guessing this is simply used whenever a noun is needed (to be down for "it", whatever that may be) and is identical in meaning to the other phrase.

Answer (score 2):

From Oxford Dictionaries ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/down ):

> **4.1** On or on to a list, schedule, or record.
>   *‘I'll put you down for the evening shift’*

So, "down to do something" means on the list to do something, or scheduled to do something, or otherwise committed to do something.

As for "down with", it's a well known colloquialism.  From the same source:

> *US informal predicative* Supporting or going along with someone or something.
>
> *‘you got to be down with me’*
>
> *‘she was totally down for a selfie’*
>
> *‘‘You going to the movies?’ ‘Yo, I'm down.’’*

And from Merriam-Webster ( https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down ):

> **5 a** *slang* :  cool - *a down dude*
>   **b** *slang* :  understanding or supportive of something or someone —usually used with *with*
>   *trying to prove that they were down with hip-hop culture — J. E. White*
>
> **6 :**  being on record - *you're down for two tickets*

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret phrase **a**.. *"cool a down dude"* ...what?? lol.

Comment: To be fair, I didn't put the word "cool" in italics here, only "a down dude", but perhaps I could format it better.  I might try to adjust it.  If you visit the linked M-W site, you might find it clearer.  To clarify, "cool" is the definition, and  "a down dude" is M-W's example of the word "down" being used to mean  "cool".

Comment: Ah! I didn't see the hyphen that separates *cool* and *a*. Makes sense now :)